# Compiz Desktop Size does not work after logout/login on MATE 1.12

Tags: compiz, mate, multiple-desktops

I have configured Compiz under `General Options -> Desktop Size` to have 8 desktops.

[image]

This works well in combination with `Desktop Wall` plugin, and I can switch over the 8 desktops with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>-+<kbd>Right</kbd>.

However, when I logout and log back in, desktop switching no longer works until I go back to `General Options -> Desktop Size` and update the number of desktops, like reducing it to 7 and then back to 8. This fixes the problem.

It seems like something that runs on login is either reconfiguring the number of desktops, or maybe just taking control over the desktops away from Compiz. What could this process be and how can I fix this?

I am running the MATE 1.12 desktop, so this is basically Gnome 2.